# In rails, when routing to an external url and using the _url helper is there a way to specify the default port number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

When routing to an external url and using the **`_url`** helper is there a way to specify the default port?

routes.rb

```
scope host: 'www.foo.com' do
  root :to => 'dev#null', as: :marketing_site
end
```

when using the _url helper, `marketing_site_url` resolves to `www.foo.com:3000`

I can get the proper url with `marketing_site_url(:port=> 80)`, but I'd prefer the port default to 80, but only on when using this helper for this external url.

Comment: I think that port 80 is already the default. Isn't it?

Comment: @Johannes I think it's using 3000 as the default in this case as that's the port for the site when running in development mode. Because it's an external URL that's probably not going to give the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that using the Rails Router is the correct way to achieve this. Instead, you could define a helper method to return the url for the site somewhere in `app/helpers`, possibly `app/helpers/marketing_site_helper.rb`.

```
def marketing_site_url
  "http://www.foo.com"
end
```

Comment: Yes, using rails router to generate links to external resources is totally not what it's meant for.